# Save data from Listview to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to save data from `ListView` to MySQL Database. Items `SubTotal`, `Cash`, and `Kembalian` should be save to MySql's table:

```
int SubTotal = 0;
int Cash = 0;
int Kembalian = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.Items.Count; i++)
{

      SubTotal = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
      Cash = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
      Kembalian = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);

      string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=elga";
      string Query = "insert into cimonedb.penjualan (SubTotal, Cash, Kembalian) values('" + SubTotal + "','" + Cash + "','" + Kembalian + "',)";
      MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
      MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
      MySqlDataReader myReader;
      try
      {
           conDataBase.Open();
           myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
           MessageBox.Show("Transsaksi is Seved");
           while (myReader.Read())
           {  

           }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this problems:

1. You have one extra comma `,` at the end of the `insert` statement.
2. You should use `cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();` instead of `cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();` and remove `while (myReader.Read()) { }`
3. You have missed `conDataBase.Close();`

Also it is better to use [`Using statement`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection) to provide a simpler way to specify when the unmanaged resource is needed.

Although your code is not vulnerable for [`SQL Injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) I strongly recommend that you always use [`parameterized queries`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).